# How to place all 3rd party libraries at one folder?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-import

I've downloaded [Google APIs Client Library for Python](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/start/installation), which comes with 4 subfolders: apiclient, httplib2, oauth2client, uritemplate.
Currently they are placed in the root folder like:

```
apiclient
httplib2
oauth2client
uritemplate
app.yaml 
...
```

and used like below:

```
import httplib2
from apiclient.discovery import build
```

But I would like to move them into one folder like:

```
lib
   apiclient
   httplib2
   oauth2client
   uritemplate
app.yaml 
...
```

How the `import` should look in this case?

Answer (score 1):

This has been asked heaps and heaps of times. The client library is no different to any other 3rd party library.

modify sys.path to include lib, or us site.add_sitedir

Do all path manipulation in appengine_config.py - See docs - about this file, which is loaded before any of your code.  https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/appengineconfig

Then your import statement is exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks. Creation of `appengine_config.py` with two lines of code - `import sys; sys.path.append('lib')` helped.

Answer (score 1):

I use the following code in appengine_config.py:

```
import os
import sys
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'external')
sys.path.insert(0, path)
```

Where 'external' is the path to my folder full of libraries.  I put it at the front in case I eclipse builtin app engine libraries (which has happened before).